# App crashing when setting new content view

Tags: java, android

Edit:

It seems my button styles are causing the issue.

Edit Code

```
buttonL.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                buttonL.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lights_over);
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
                buttonL.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lights);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The code above is what works for 4.2 and up for some reason.

### Putting it here for future people.

---

My app is crashing when I try to call the `setContentView()` method to my **layout**.

I tried a few solutions and when I removed my styles for my buttons the error went away.

It seems that the styles I am using for my buttons is causing this.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/lights_over" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/lights_over" />
<item android:state_selected = "true" android:drawable = "@drawable/lights_over" />
<item android:drawable = "@drawable/lights" android:id="@+id/button_L"/>
</selector>
```

My LogCat

```
01-09 12:04:24.161: D/dalvikvm(20682): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 5% free 122880K/129056K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
01-09 12:04:24.161: E/dalvikvm-heap(20682): Out of memory on a 9027940-byte allocation.
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidexample.broadcastreceiver/com.androidexample.broadcastreceiver.StartMenu}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #79: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:151)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #79: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:327)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at com.androidexample.broadcastreceiver.StartMenu.onCreate(StartMenu.java:20)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5250)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    ... 11 more
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    ... 25 more
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:817)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2854)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1521)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:921)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:858)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2839)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3460)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:791)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:103)
01-09 12:04:24.171: E/AndroidRuntime(20682):    ... 28 more
```

Comment: The main error I see that can help those reading this is `01-09 12:29:02.551: E/AndroidRuntime(22418):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
01-09 12:29:02.551: E/AndroidRuntime(22418):  at com.androidexample.broadcastreceiver.StartMenu.onCreate(StartMenu.java:20)`
That is where I call the setContentView method

Comment: Must Check that the background image in your xml file is high resolution images?

Comment: The image is 120kb. It works on 4 different tablets, 2 different phones with different android version on it. The only place where the app crashes is with an Galaxy S4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From logcat the problem is background of your Button. I think it's somehow big image so it overflow your memory.

**First**
Try to remove any @drawable in menu_system.xml especially android:background in Button
Run your if it's work then you know where to look.

**Second(for workaround)**
Move your background image file to bigger folder
from drawable to drawable-xhdpi

Comment: It is in the xhdpi folder atm. I will try the first thing and let you know.

Comment: Zinuzoid, it seems that my problem is my button styles. I am using rollover images to simulate someone touching the screen. I will try to fix that. Thank you for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Thread splash=new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(2000);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),StartMenu.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    };

    splash.start();
}
```

And your Manifest.xml:

```
 <activity
 android:name="com.example.mapcard.Splash"
 android:label="@string/app_name" >
 <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Comment: my manifest.xml already has the correct labels and such in. I tried your code for the splash screen. I get the same errors.

Comment: Check your line: }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT); seems a runtime error will occur.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code .It was working fine.I think issue is because of out of memory.Issue is with image resource ,try to set image in compressed format to avoid memory leakage.

Comment: Hi there. What do you mean compressed format? Also my code works on 6 out of the 7 devices I tested it on. Only one has this issue.